# Groovy 2d array

Tags: groovy

I want to have a collection like this

```
[item1: [123, 123, 2321], item2: [1231,1222,1313]]
```

I tried using a map like this `[  : [] ]` but this is not allowed. How can I achieve the following structure. I want to add element using a string as a key:

```
content['item1'] << 123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all works correctly, you use a `Map` - not 2D array:

```
def m = [item1: [123, 123, 2321], item2: [1231,1222,1313]]
m['item1'] << 1234
println(m)
```

If you need a declaration it can be done in the following way:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> m = [:]
```

however it will be erased at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if I got your question correctly but if you want to know how to use `Array` then well, the same way as in Java

To declare an array use

```
String [][] array
```

Do initialize an array

```
array = new String [1][2] // matrix 1x2
```

To read/write into such array

```
array [0][0] = 'Foo'
array [0][1] = 'Bar'
```

Unfortunately (at least to my knowledge) declare/init the Java way doesn't work in Groovy

```
String [][] a = new String [][]{{'Hi','Hello'}} // won't compile in Groovy
```